# Run JAR file on remote Host 24x7

Tags: java, jar, udp, hosting

I have a JAR file which i am running on my home computer.
But i cannot run it 24X7 because of power /internet outages.

JAR contains->
UDP DatagramChannel , JDBC to update MySQL DB, Multithreaded , Executor Pool.

The direct answer would be to buy a VPS but that is not an option because VPS costs 100$ per month , So its **expensive** to start as the JAR application is currently small.

Cheap shared webhosts dont allow **Listening to ports** (required for UDP channels).

How should i proceed.

```
JAR takes around 50K Memory and 15KBps Network IO. which will increase in future.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average VPS costs much less than $100 a month - it's possible to get a cheap one for more like $3/month.

Comment: really? I can't say Ive ever seen them anywhere near that cheap, webhosts yes, shared hosting yes, not VPS though.  Not $100 either mind, but never seen them as low as $3.

Comment: Problem is with UDP Packet Listening. Even Hostgator  terms say you cannot run UDP Packet Listening if i am not wrong .

Comment: I've never personally encountered a VPS provider who blocked UDP. The one I just linked to doesn't seem to (not that I've ever used them).

Comment: Thanks, Some hostings object to UDP "GAME" packets because people run Dedicated game servers on them.